# Calling service from a function angular2

Tags: javascript, angular2-services

I'm trying to call a service from a function but i'm getting this error in the console:

> Cannot read property 'TestMethod' of undefined

This is my code:

- app.component.ts:

  ```
  constructor(public _service: BackendFileCodeService){
  }
  public editor;

   EditorCreated(quill) {
       const toolbar = quill.getModule('toolbar');
       this.editor = quill;
        // console.log(quill)
        toolbar.addHandler('image', this.imageHandler);
  }
  imageHandler(value) {
            //   document.querySelector('input.ql-image[type=file]').addEventListener('click', () => {
            //      console.log('Hello');
            //   });
            const ImageInput = document.createElement('input');
            ImageInput.setAttribute('type', 'file');
            ImageInput.setAttribute('accept', 'image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/bmp, image/x-icon');
            ImageInput.classList.add('ql-image');
            ImageInput.click();

            ImageInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
                const file = ImageInput.files[0];
                if (ImageInput.files != null && ImageInput.files[0] != null) {
                  this._service.TestMethod('Hello');
                     }
            });
        }
  ```
- BackendFileCodeService:

  ```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  @Injectable()
  export class BackendFileCodeService {
       constructor() { }
      TestMethod(test){
      return test;
      }
  }
  ```

I'm trying to call the service inside the function called imageHandler specifically in the

> ImageInput.addEventListener

but i'm getting the error mentioned up, i tried to call the service from outside the imageHandler function and every this works as expected.

Note: the service is console log 'hello' as test.

Answer (score 0):

Using fat arrow syntax for your imageHandler function should resolve the issue.

```
imageHandler(value) {...}
...
imageHandler = (value) => { ... }
```

If you can not use fat arrow syntax, you would need to create a variable to capture the component scope, the most common way is declaring a variable and assigning to this,

```
self = this;
imageHandler(value) {
 ....
 self._service.TestMethod('Hello');
 ....
}
```

I see you are aalready using fat arrow syntax below, which is good else you would also need to capture scope for `imageHandler`.

```
ImageInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
```

Read more about [function scopes in typescript here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html),

> **this** and **arrow functions**
>
> In JavaScript, this is a variable that’s set when a function is
> called. This makes it a very powerful and flexible feature, but it
> comes at the cost of always having to know about the context that a
> function is executing in. This is notoriously confusing, especially
> when returning a function or passing a function as an argument.